# Google Maps: Checking if a polyline passes thru a circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to ask how do I check if a certain Polyline passes thru a Circle? In the image below, the red polyline passes inside the green circle. I know it is possible to determine if a marker is within a circle but i don't know how to do it or if it is feasible for polylines.

I still have 8 reputation points so I can't post images, here's the link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fzXu.png

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably do the following:

1. Get bound of circle.
2. Filter the polyline coordinates and find the points that fall into that bound.
3. Calculate distance between circle center and each of those points. (circle/bound center can be easily obtained by some built-in method)
4. If any distance < circle radius, it gives you result.

Only problem with this algo is, if your polyline goes through the circle but your list of popyline coordinates does not contain one that falls in the bound. I haven't come up with a solution for that yet :)